# How to get a pointer to AFX_MODULE_STATE of a DLL?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc

Our MFC-project is split into an exe and several dlls, which may also contain MFC-dialogs. For loading such a dialog, the dll contains an exported dll function. We have troubles loading the right resources for the dialog.

At the moment, the function looks like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int ShowDialog()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstOld = AfxGetResourceHandle();
    AfxSetResourceHandle(DXFDECDLL.hResource);
    CMyDllDialog dlg;
    AfxSetResourceHandle(hInstOld);
    dlg.DoModal();
    return 1;
}
```

It is working (most of the time), but seems to be bad. The function `AfxSetResourceHandle` sets the resource handle of the current AFX_MODULE_STATE and this module state is the one of the exe. If some other thread tries to load a string from the resource in the meantime, it will fail.

I think, we have to change the active module state, but I don't know how.

I have read the following article, but its guildlines fail.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn058-mfc-module-state-implementation?view=msvc-170

1. The AFX_MODULE_STATE does not seem to be changed automatically, if I load the DLL with `LoadLibrary` and calling the method via a function pointer. Do I need to edit the automatically generated `DLLMain`?
2. If I try to call `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` in my function ShowDialog, I get a linker error LINK2005: "_DLLMain@12 is already defined in DXFDEC.obj"

---

Concerning the comment of @IInspectable, here is a minimal example, which generates a linker error. It is generated by the Visual Studio code generator. I have just added the function `MyFunction`

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxdllx.h>

static AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE MFCLibrary3DLL = { false, nullptr };

extern "C" int APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        if (!AfxInitExtensionModule(MFCLibrary3DLL, hInstance))
            return 0;

        new CDynLinkLibrary(MFCLibrary3DLL);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        AfxTermExtensionModule(MFCLibrary3DLL);
    }
    return 1;   // OK
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyFunction()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` is the correct way to (temporarily) switch resource lookup to the module containing the executing code. If you run into linker errors, you will have to determine what's causing it. Start by deducing a [mcve]. The documentation on [Extension DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/extension-dlls) is likely helpful in figuring out the relevant configuration settings (and potential mismatches).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your comment. I have added the example at the end of the text.

Comment: MFC provides a `DllMain` implementation for Extension DLLs (see *dllmodul.cpp*). Its `InternalDllMain` implementation does what your re-implementation does. The solution is probably as simple as deleting your `DllMain` implementation. I cannot answer the question as to why the linker error only starts surfacing after using `AFX_MANAGE_STATE`.

Comment: Deleting the ```DllMain``` is not an option. The upper code is just a minimal example, but we need to do some initialization, i.e. changing the memory handling for the ```CDynLinkLibrary``` object.

Comment: Though I haven't looked, I'm fairly sure that MFC provides customization points that would allow you to hook into the system and set up things the way you need them. I'll see if I can look into this some more later today, once I'm at a machine with more than just a single display. I would help to understand what kind of *"memory handling"* you need, though.